# Python - Float variable always returning as largest in comparative

Tags: python, variables, int, python-2.x

I am experiencing problems with a variable in my code. Here is part of my code:

```
import re
name = raw_input("Input the Character's name: ")
name = name.lower()

season = raw_input("Input the season: ")

rainyday = raw_input("Is it a rainy day? ")
total_time = raw_input("What time is it?(Input as e.g 1.30 am")
non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
timel = non_decimal.sub('', total_time)
float(timel)
print timel
#ALEX
if name == "alex":
    if rainyday == "yes":
        if "am" in total_time:
            if time > 8.00:
                print("He's in the entryway of his house until 1:00 PM")
            else:
                print("He's in his room until 8:00 AM")
                print("!")
        elif timel < 1:
            print("He's in the entryway of his room until 1:00 PM")
            print("y")
        elif timel < 4.2:
            print("He's leaving his room to go to the dog pen until 6:30 PM")
        elif timel < 6.3:
            print("He's at the dog pen until 6:30")
        elif timel < 8.0:
            print("He's in the entryway of his house until 8:00 P.M")
        elif timel < 10.0:
            print("He's standing by the dresser in his room")
        else:
            print("He's sleeping")
```

Whenever I input total_time as a number with "pm" with it, I get the else statement, "He's sleeping"
These lines of code I ran on the shell illustrate my problem:

```
>>> print timel
2
>>> timel < 3
False
>>> 2 < 3
True
>>> timel < 1000000000
False
```

It seems that timel is always an undefined number which is larger than everything else, even though it has been defined. I would greatly appreciate help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
timel = non_decimal.sub('', total_time)
float(timel)
```

that last line doesn't convert `timel` to float. `float` doesn't work in-place.

After that `timel` is still a string, and compares without errors but with strange/unexpected result with integers/floats in python 2 (in python 3 it fails with an exception (`unorderable types: str() < int()`), which at least points out the error)

fix:

```
timel = float(non_decimal.sub('', total_time))
```

Comment: Or, the last line could be `timel = float(timel)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `float(timel)` to convert the string in to a float number.

`float( a )` does return `a` converted to a float, but does not touch the original parameter.

Thus, the line should be `timel = float(timel)` to actually convert `timel`